# Getting an error creating a GCP resource using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, compiler-errors, terraform, google-vpc

I am trying to create a resource by using the terraform.

Here is the code

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "evident-plane-403213"
  credentials = file("evident-plane-403213-1b4230892244.json")
  region      = "us-central1"
  zone        = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "my-instance" {
  name                      = "terraform-instance"
  machine_type              = "f1-micro"
  zone                      = "us-central1"
  allow_stopping_for_update = true

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-10"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network    = google_compute_network.terraform_network.self_link
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.terraform_subnet.self_link
    access_config {
      // Keeping it empty. It will access over the internet.
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_network" "terrform_network" {
  name                    = "terraform-network"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "terraform_subnet" {
  name          = "terraform-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.20.0.0/15"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.terraform_network.id
}
```

My resource is not getting created and I am getting some error

> │ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
> │
> │   on main.tf line 33, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "terraform_subnet":
> │   33:   network       = google_compute_network.terraform_network.id
> │
> │ A managed resource "google_compute_network" "terraform_network" has not been
> │ declared in the root module.

Where is the error? please help and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your resource:

```
resource "google_compute_network" "terrform_network" {
```

You have a typo in the resource name. It is named `terrform_network`. It is missing the `a` in `terraform`.

Later, when you try to reference it, you include the `a`:

```
network       = google_compute_network.terraform_network.id
```

So the name of the resource doesn't match the name you try to reference later.

Comment: Opps. Thanks @Mark